# Is it possible to auto-uncover a Beamer frame with overlays?

Tags: beamer, overlays, linux, pause

For a standard Beamer presentation with overlays, items are uncovered by the click of a button (or similar). I have a presentation where I would like a particular slide to auto-uncover one item at a time with a delay. Is that possible?

I include a fictive MWE below. Fictive, since the \delay{n} command does not exist. Is there something that does the equivalent? I have googled and checked the manual to the best of my imagination, but not found anything.
My platform is linux, so `evince` is my viewer, if that makes any difference.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1 --- Manual uncover}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Items
\item<2-> are uncovered
\item<3-> by the click
\item<4-> of a button.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2 --- Auto-uncover}

\begin{itemize}
\item Items \delay{3}
\item are uncovered \delay{3}
\item every 3 seconds.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 3 --- Normal}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Items
\item<2-> are uncovered
\item<3-> by the click
\item<4-> of a button.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable automatic slide changes with `\transduration<0-2>{<time in seconds>}`, however not all pdf viewer support this (it works with adobe reader in presentation mode).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2 --- Auto-uncover}
\transduration<0-2>{0.5}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Items 
\item are uncovered
\item every 3 seconds.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to work with `pdfpc` which is a pdf oriented-presentation viewer available on Linux.